# Windows start menu's autocomplete keystrokes?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, start-menu, autocomplete

From the Windows 10 desktop, without mousing, I can launch the default app for e.g. `c:\fooooo\barrrr.jpg` by typing

```
<windows logo>c:\fo
<tab>
shift+<tab>
\bar
<tab>
shift+<tab>
<enter>
```

where `<tab> shift+<tab>` autocompletes fo to fooooo, and then bar to barrrr.

Is there a shorter sequence of keystrokes from the desktop?

The official [list of keyboard shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10) is long, and none of its sections seems to apply.

(File Explorer doesn't need the extra `shift+<tab>`.  It can start mouseless with `<logo>+E Alt+D`.)

Comment: If you start the first 2 or 3 characters, enter completes it properly (here)

Comment: True, unless there's multiple matches, in which case a list of candidates appears that you can arrow down through.  But only sometimes, unlike File Explorer.  I'll keep experimenting.